Ghoscript throws GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete Output may be incorrect
I am using ghostscript in AWS lambda functions to generate pdf thumnail. it works for most of the pdfs but for some pdf it throws some error.
ERROR   Error: Command failed: ./bin/gs -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=png16m -dPDFFitPage=true -dBackgroundColor=16#FFFFFF -dUseCropBox -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r72 -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=/tmp/'e06e8302-add7-4dfe-99c8-2e54b8ffcbce_5153997.png' /tmp/'e06e8302-add7-4dfe-99c8-2e54b8ffcbce_5153997.pdf'
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:422:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5) {
  code: 1,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: "./bin/gs -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=png16m -dPDFFitPage=true -dBackgroundColor=16#FFFFFF -dUseCropBox -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r72 -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=/tmp/'e06e8302-add7-4dfe-99c8-2e54b8ffcbce_5153997.png' /tmp/'e06e8302-add7-4dfe-99c8-2e54b8ffcbce_5153997.pdf'",
  stdout: '   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.\n' +
    '               Output may be incorrect.\n' +
    '\n' +
    "   **** Error: File has unbalanced q/Q operators (too many Q's)\n" +
    '               Output may be incorrect.\n' +
    "   **** Error: Form stream has unbalanced q/Q operators (too many q's)\n" +
    '               Output may be incorrect.\n' +
    '   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.\n' +
    '               Output may be incorrect.\n' +
    "   **** Error: Form stream has unbalanced q/Q operators (too many q's)\n" +
    '               Output may be incorrect.\n' +
    '   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.\n' +
    '               Output may be incorrect.\n' +
    "   **** Error: Form stream has unbalanced q/Q operators (too many q's)\n" +
    '               Output may be incorrect.\n' +
    'Error: /unregistered in /--pdfshowpage_finish--\n' +
    'Operand stack:\n' +
    '\n' +
    'Execution stack:\n' +
    '   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   pdfshowpage_finish   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   pdfshowpage_finish   pdfshowpage_finish   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3   %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1962   1   3   %oparray_pop   pdfshowpage_finish   pdfshowpage_finish   2   1   1   pdfshowpage_finish   %for_pos_int_continue   1965   1   7   %oparray_pop   pdfshowpage_finish   pdfshowpage_finish\n' +
    'Dictionary stack:\n' +
    '   --dict:736/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:133/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:320/325(ro)(G)--   --dict:31/32(L)--   --dict:6/9(L)--   --dict:6/20(L)--\n' +
    'Current allocation mode is local\n' +
    'Last OS error: Permission denied\n',
  stderr: 'GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1\n'
}

i am using gs_10.02.1_amd64_snap extracted it and using only four files to generate thumbnail.

below is my command i used to generate thumbnail.
./bin/gs -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=png16m -dPDFFitPage=true -dBackgroundColor=16#FFFFFF -dUseCropBox -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r72 -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=${directory}'${newUUID + "" + randomNumber}.png' ${directory}'${newUUID + "" + randomNumber}.pdf'

OK, you are not using Ghostscript 10.02.1 as your snap name suggests. You are using 9.53.3, as given by the back channel report there. 9.53.3 is 3 years old. The current version is 10.03.0, I'd suggest you try that. You also need to find out why you are using such an old version rather than the version you think you are using. If current code exhibits the same problem you should open a bug report at bugs.ghostscript.com. You will need to attach an example file which demonstrates your problem because nobody can investigate it without that.

@KenS Where can i download the latest version. i want to use it in lambda function AWS. there i can't upload file graeter than 250MB  can you please tell me how can install and use it or any source where i can refer.

I cannot help you at all with AWS. The current version of Ghostscript is available to download from https://www.ghostscript.com/releases/index.html but obviously you will have to compile the source. I'd suggest you build Ghostscript locally and try your file with that before going to the effort of building GS on AWS. You may as well find out if the problem is fixed in current code first.
